# Google Maps v2 Error on use of setMyLocationEnabled

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I am not sure were I went wrong, getting a `nullPointerException` on using `googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` in Google Map v2 example.

**MainActivity.java File:**

```
package com.example.locationgooglemapsv2;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    /*======== MAP TYPE ==========*/

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    RadioGroup rgViews = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_views);

    rgViews.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.normal:   googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                                break;

            case R.id.satellite:googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                                break;

            case R.id.terrain:  googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                                break;
            }
        }
    });


    /*======== MARKER AND ONCLICK ==========*/

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOption.position(latlng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            //markerOption.title(latlng.latitude + " : " + latlng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);

            // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
            new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latlng);

        }
    });



    /*======== LOCATION ==========*/


     // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

    //--maps
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*======== REVERSE GEO CODING ==========*/

class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{

    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask( Context con) {

        super();
        this.mContext = con;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        double lat = params[0].latitude;
        double lng = params[0].longitude;

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String actualAdress = "";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            actualAdress = String.format("%s, %s, %s", address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getLocality(), address.getCountryName());
        }

        return actualAdress;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(result);

        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

}

}
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.locationgooglemapsv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapsv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Error Log:**

```
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locationgooglemapsv2/com.example.locationgooglemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at com.example.locationgooglemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-11 21:11:56.282: E/AndroidRuntime(327):  ... 11 more
```

BTW the source is a good example for those who are trying to play with `google map v2` and is well commented.

Any help regarding the error is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "API_KEY" does not exist in your manifest. Please Insert Your "API_KEY" .

Comment: @BBonDoo I have inserted my api key in actual program.

Comment: @YKM..OK that you got your API_KEY. Now I found that your build target in your manifest is "<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"..>. Please change that setting into ""android:minSdkVersion="7" and run your project again. In Android 2.2 (API 8), it's likely to get the failed result because android 2.2 has been known to have the Reverse geocoding bug. If you got the same failed results, restart your eclipse and try to run again. Please let me know your result.

Comment: Before setting "android:minSdkVersion="7" in your manifest, you must install "Google APIs 7(Android 2.1)" in the SDK Manager. If do so, your project will work fine.

Comment: @BBonDoo Sorry for late reply But I am trying to run on GingerBread, I guess atleast it should have shown on that if not Froyo. Please correctify me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getmap()` is returning null. That means the map is not ready.  Either because the fragment is not ready or your are running on a device without Google Play services available.  See [getMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMap%28%29) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting something simular due to the Google Play Services API being missing from the device.  If you use:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)
```

It should return ConnectionResult.SUCCESS if available. if it returns

```
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED
```

you can prompt the user to download it using

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the googleplayservice to test this workflow?

Comment: I think its removable from your device through the applications menu.