# google maps api v2

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-virtual-device, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to run a basic example of Google maps API v2 from http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html but it keeps crashing with an error:

```
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4716)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-10 14:51:38.292: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my code...

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="{tried both browser api key and android api keys here}" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
package com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel =
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

of ran it on an AVD with target Google API 17, it crashes immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you have not added protection for Google Play Services, the Google Maps V2 api requires this to run.

The issue maybe due to Google Play Services not being supported on AVD. Try running on a device.

maybe these can help

[Missing Google Play Services from AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784198/missing-google-play-services-from-avd)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282347/1788333

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand what those protections are. Beside checking for play services availability on AVD and trying to run on a real device, is there anything else I should do?

Comment: the protections are to test to see if Google play services are available on the device as it is not installed by default.[here is a link to the google page](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) - also i'm sure you have already, but double check you have downloaded the Google play services API from the SDK manager

Answer (score 0):

You should extend **FragmentActivity** than Activity.

Use this in your activity:
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

And in xml in **fragment tag**  write this:

class="com.google.android.gms.maps.**SupportMapFragment**"