# Android Application Crashing asking for Android ID

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, google-maps

I am developing a Google map v2 Android application. It is crashing and not opening at all. I followed the tutorial by Google developers and got an API key that I used in the Manifest file

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest file**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCx7eq9mnY609bDebfAEeBLx8L2Exw8J30" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

**This is the logcat**

```
12-27 14:12:43.490: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:13:13.410: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 324K, 13% free 2960K/3368K, paused 132ms, total 133ms
12-27 14:13:16.970: D/dalvikvm(766): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libAppDataSearch.so 0xb3d364a0, skipping init
12-27 14:13:17.060: D/Icing(766): Default language: en
12-27 14:13:17.830: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 0
12-27 14:13:18.930: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 1
12-27 14:13:18.930: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 2
12-27 14:13:18.930: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 3
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 4
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 5
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 6
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 7
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 8
12-27 14:13:19.120: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 9
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 10
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 11
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 12
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 13
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 14
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 15
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 16
12-27 14:13:19.130: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 17
12-27 14:13:19.200: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 18
12-27 14:13:19.200: D/Icing(766): Upgrading storage to version to 19
12-27 14:13:19.200: E/Icing(766): Opening file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.h for write failed: No such file or directory
12-27 14:13:19.200: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.h
12-27 14:13:19.200: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.n
12-27 14:13:19.210: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.x
12-27 14:13:19.210: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.s
12-27 14:13:19.210: E/Icing(766): Couldn't create a URI mapping store
12-27 14:13:19.210: E/Icing(766): Couldn't upgrade native from version -1 to 26
12-27 14:13:19.210: E/Icing(766): Clearing storage
12-27 14:13:21.650: D/Icing(766): Clearing docstore and index
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.index
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.h
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.n
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.x
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.s
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.deleted
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.h
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.n
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.x
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.s
12-27 14:13:21.720: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.deleted
12-27 14:13:21.830: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.hb
12-27 14:13:21.830: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lexicon.h
12-27 14:13:21.830: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lexicon.n
12-27 14:13:21.830: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lexicon.x
12-27 14:13:21.840: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lexicon.s
12-27 14:13:21.840: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lexicon.deleted
12-27 14:13:21.840: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.display.h
12-27 14:13:21.840: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.display.n
12-27 14:13:21.840: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.display.x
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.display.s
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.display.deleted
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Clearing /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur from uninitialized state
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Removing all document store files for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.docids
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.perdocdata
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.cscoring
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.docs
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.h
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.n
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.x
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.s
12-27 14:13:21.850: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.urifps.deleted
12-27 14:13:21.930: D/Icing(766): Init last flush num docs 0 last docstore size 0
12-27 14:13:21.930: D/Icing(766): Docid map file has no data, nothing to scan
12-27 14:13:22.310: D/Icing(766): File /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.perdocdata contains 0 records of size 6
12-27 14:13:22.810: D/Icing(766): Init docstore ok num docs 0 bytes 0
12-27 14:13:23.330: D/Icing(766): Block size 0: 4080
12-27 14:13:23.330: D/Icing(766): Block size 1: 2040
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 2: 1020
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 3: 510
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 4: 255
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 5: 125
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 6: 60
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 7: 30
12-27 14:13:23.340: D/Icing(766): Block size 8: 15
12-27 14:13:24.120: V/Icing(766): Creating new hit buffer
12-27 14:13:24.250: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.h
12-27 14:13:24.550: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.n
12-27 14:13:24.550: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.x
12-27 14:13:24.550: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.s
12-27 14:13:24.860: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.lexicon.deleted
12-27 14:13:25.190: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.h
12-27 14:13:25.190: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.n
12-27 14:13:25.190: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.x
12-27 14:13:25.190: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.s
12-27 14:13:25.350: D/Icing(766): Deleting file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/idx.lite.display.deleted
12-27 14:13:25.510: V/Icing(766): Lite index crc computed in 1.692ms
12-27 14:13:25.510: V/Icing(766): Lite index created ok
12-27 14:13:25.520: V/Icing(766): Warming lite-index took 0.264ms
12-27 14:13:25.520: V/Icing(766): Warming lexicon took 0.084ms
12-27 14:13:25.520: V/Icing(766): Warming display mappings took 0.071ms
12-27 14:13:25.520: D/Icing(766): Init index ok num docs 0
12-27 14:13:25.520: D/Icing(766): Init done
12-27 14:13:40.790: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 432K, 15% free 3040K/3556K, paused 158ms, total 161ms
12-27 14:13:41.470: W/ContextImpl(766): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.init.InitializeGmsReceiver.onReceive:29 
12-27 14:13:48.750: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:13:49.730: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 431K, 15% free 3121K/3636K, paused 579ms, total 582ms
12-27 14:14:25.701: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:14:25.741: W/ContextImpl(766): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.init.InitializeGmsReceiver.onReceive:29 
12-27 14:14:34.611: I/PeopleSync(766): First sync
12-27 14:14:36.881: I/LocationInitializer(766): Initiliazing location.
12-27 14:14:37.001: I/PeopleDatabaseHelper(766): cleanUpNonGplusAccounts done.
12-27 14:14:37.081: I/PeopleSearchIndexManage(766): ICU version changed from unknown to 51.1.0.1
12-27 14:14:37.161: I/PeopleSearchIndexManage(766): Rebuilding index...
12-27 14:14:37.591: I/PeopleSearchIndexManage(766): Rebuilding index done.
12-27 14:14:37.641: V/GA-SERVICE(766): Thread[IntentService[InitializeIntentService],5,main]: Update service enabled state to: 2
12-27 14:14:37.991: E/MDM(766): Missing android_id
12-27 14:14:38.141: E/ProtoRequest(766): want to send authenticated request, but no Google account on device
12-27 14:14:38.961: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 355K, 12% free 3277K/3716K, paused 128ms, total 153ms
12-27 14:14:41.651: W/ActivityThread(766): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
12-27 14:14:42.101: D/Volley(766): [115] ot.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://android.googleapis.com/nova/sitrep 0x58872a44 NORMAL 3> [lifetime=3869], [size=0], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
12-27 14:14:42.171: V/AuthZen(1251): Received a GCM message.
12-27 14:14:42.271: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 436K, 14% free 3356K/3876K, paused 101ms, total 105ms
12-27 14:14:42.421: D/Volley(766): [1] oa.b: 4273 ms: [ ] https://android.googleapis.com/nova/sitrep 0x58872a44 NORMAL 3
12-27 14:14:45.611: V/AuthZen(1251): Authzen is disabled
12-27 14:15:05.181: V/AuthZen(1251): Received broadcast action: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
12-27 14:15:05.281: V/AuthZen(1251): Received a GCM message.
12-27 14:15:05.371: V/AuthZen(1251): Authzen is disabled
12-27 14:15:35.941: W/ContextImpl(766): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.init.InitializeGmsReceiver.onReceive:29 
12-27 14:15:41.611: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 492K, 15% free 3372K/3952K, paused 671ms, total 692ms
12-27 14:15:42.721: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=
12-27 14:15:42.761: W/ContextImpl(766): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.games.service.INTENT } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.a:101 com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.b:368 
12-27 14:15:49.411: W/ContextImpl(766): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.google.android.gms.init.InitializeGmsReceiver.onReceive:29 
12-27 14:15:49.811: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:15:50.211: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:15:52.031: V/GA-SERVICE(766): Thread[IntentService[RefreshEnabledStateService],5,main]: Update service enabled state to: 2
12-27 14:15:55.421: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:15:55.781: D/SystemBroadcastService(766): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=
12-27 14:15:56.231: I/GCM(766): Message from Bundle[{registration_id=APA91bGB2_ju83eBD1jWGGKwz-4P4zCyKgPYs-v2hlH8B2Rl2jauU9Hip6oFKRL6LmrWWhzVsAhJtn-CdTAfkEMJWWtxvoIlkvwlTteBXNb3O51O7haOvAk1QGLkKd8r1i8yTyGwsC4XGyt5WNJX1LUrAecpp-4ktA}] null
12-27 14:15:58.531: V/GA-SERVICE(766): Thread[IntentService[RefreshEnabledStateService],5,main]: Update service enabled state to: 2
12-27 14:15:58.991: D/dalvikvm(766): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 494K, 15% free 3390K/3968K, paused 332ms, total 332ms
12-27 14:15:59.511: W/Uploader(766): No account for auth token provided
12-27 14:16:01.281: V/GA-SERVICE(766): Thread[IntentService[RefreshEnabledStateService],5,main]: Update service enabled state to: 2
12-27 14:16:03.131: W/Uploader(766): No account for auth token provided
```

Comment: change min sdk to 12 in manifest. and this in application tag `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running it on an AVD that does not have the Google API's. Check to make sure the Google API's are are part of your AVD (beware of licensing problems on 2.3: https://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/issues/detail?id=27)

You may have to use a real device: [google maps api v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799081/google-maps-api-v2)

Even with Google API's, it looks like you need to make sure your AVD has a Google Account setup on it.